# CSS width:100% textarea for comment (responsive)

Tags: html, css

I need little help for my CSS.

I am trying to make a comment system but it has something went wrong.

This is my [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/RPryvz) page from *codepen.io*

You can see there is a user avatar and textarea. The container `max-width:650px;` when you reduced width the browser the it is automatically changing.

anyone can help me in this regard?

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="comment">
    <div class="commenter">
      <img src="https://igcdn-photos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xta1/t51.2885-19/11084950_1591056347778266_1536322251_a.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="comment-text-area">
      <textarea class="textinput" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 650px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.comment {
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.commenter {
  float: left;
}

.commenter img {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
}

.comment-text-area {
  float: left;
  width:100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: red;
}

.textinput {
  float:left;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 35px;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
}
```

I want to make it like this:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try using `calc();` to perform the calculation for you... baring in mind you would need to add the vendor prefixes to this.

```css
body {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 650px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.comment {
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.commenter {
  float: left;
}

.commenter img {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
}

.comment-text-area {
  float: right;
  width: calc(100% - 45px);
  height: auto;
  background-color: red;
}

.textinput {
  float:left;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 35px;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="comment">
    <div class="commenter">
      <img src="https://igcdn-photos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xta1/t51.2885-19/11084950_1591056347778266_1536322251_a.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="comment-text-area">
      <textarea class="textinput" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

as an option instead of float use display: table

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 650px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-top: 50px;    
}

.comment {
  background-color: #00f;  
  height: auto;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.commenter,
.comment-text-area{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.commenter{
  width: 35px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.commenter img {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
}

.comment-text-area {  
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  /*background-color: red;*/  
}

.textinput {  
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 35px;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="comment">
    <div class="commenter">
      <img src="https://igcdn-photos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xta1/t51.2885-19/11084950_1591056347778266_1536322251_a.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="comment-text-area">
      <textarea class="textinput" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For scenarios like this I combine `float:left;`and  `float:none;` The avatar wrapper div gets the  `float:left;` and the comment wrapper div gets the  `float:none;`.

The trick here is to put `padding-left` on the  `float:none;` div equal to the width of the  `float:left;` div.

```
.comment {
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.commenter {
  float: left;
  width:35px;
}

.commenter img {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
}

.comment-text-area {
  float: none; 
  height: auto;
  background-color: red;
    padding-left:35px;
}
```

Here is a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jdmnoxvx/)

Answer (score 0):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/vj2qntzj/)

I have changed your CSS a little bit. See the changes below. The problem with your CSS was that you used no width for `.commenter`. Thus it took default 100% width.

CSS

```
.commenter {
    float: left;
    width: 6%;
}
.comment-text-area {
    float: left;
    width: 94%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: red;
}
```

EDIT

use width for `.commenter` as `width: 35px;`..I chose 35px because it is the width of the avatar image.

Comment: This looks terrible when you resize the result area. `.commenter` should probably have a fixed width.

Comment: Thanks for your respond @lal but it i change the browser reduced then avatar has a problem.

Answer (score 0):

only change `.comment-text-area` `height:94%`

```css
body {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 650px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.comment {
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.commenter {
  float: left;
}

.commenter img {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
}

.comment-text-area {
  float: left;
  width: 94%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: red;
}

.textinput {
  float:left;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 35px;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="comment">
    <div class="commenter">
      <img src="https://igcdn-photos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xta1/t51.2885-19/11084950_1591056347778266_1536322251_a.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="comment-text-area">
      <textarea class="textinput" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can give the class name `form-control` to the `<textarea>` like this:

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="3" cols="90" ></textarea>
```

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms_inputs.asp